# SSRS - Total column sum of row

Tags: reporting-services

[image]

I have data as shown below at picture I want to show the sum of each row in total column so I made expression as shown but I am wondering

is that efficient way to sum each row in total column ?

```
=Sum(
Fields!U.Value+
Fields!PG.Value+
Fields!12.Value+
Fields!F12A.Value+
Fields!15.Value+
Fields!18.Value+
Fields!Unknown.Value
)
```

Comment: As your dataset has 1 column per age rating, then this is the only way to do it. However, if you have pivoted the original data as part of your dataset query, then it would be better to not pivot it, use a matrix in your report and then you can add a simple row total.